# Docker container showing wrong disk size

Tags: mysql, docker, diskspace

I have a mysql container running, if I run:

```
docker container ls -s
# 3.09MB (virtual 450MB)
```

However if I run inside the container:

```
du -h /var/lib/mysql/test/
14G
```

I have no volumes set up.

What is the extend of `docker container ls -s` command? It seems not to show mysql data consumption. What command can I use to show total disk consumption of a running container?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a command that will show the current disk useagage of a running container. The issue is there are multiple parts because of the layered filesystem and volume mounts:

1. each filesystem layer from the image
2. container specific writable layer
3. any data on volumes

What the docker command is likely indicating is the sum of item 1. However, even this is only a half truth because one layer may be shared between multiple images and multiple containers. In other words, if you add these up for all containers, you can end up with a number greater than all disk usage on the host.

From inside the container, a `du` command will show the result of the assembled layers, including the container writable layer, which can under report disk space since one layer may hide files from a previous filesystem layer. But it will also show usage in files that are not in the image or container filesystems. So there is no 1:1 mapping from this command to actual disk usage.

Volumes further complicate this because they mount files from outside of the layered filesystem. Even if you don't define a volume, an anonymous volume will be created for you if the image creator defines a volume on a path.

Docker commands likely don't show the actual disk usage because the time to run that command is unbounded, requiring a recursive walk of the directory tree, and the result could change before that walk is complete. However, if you want to compute this yourself, the needed steps include:

1. add up the disk space for each layer of the image, possibly dividing this among other containers based on the same layer
2. add up the disk space for the container writable layer
3. add up the disk space for each volume mount

The paths for these are visible in an container inspect command. Note that 1 will be error prone since containers can be quickly created and destroyed that used shared layers. And 3 is error prone because it's perfectly acceptable to mount the root filesystem from the host, making the container recursively report it is using all of the files on the entire host, which descends into the container, and repeats.